# "shake is not supported on real devices" error message

Tags: ios, appium

I'm using a keyword "Shake Device" for iOS v. 11.4.1 and using `XCUITest` driver and appium version 1.13. I get this error message

> shake is not supported on real devices.

According to appium.io it should be supported
http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/interactions/shake/

The Code I used is `driver.ShakeDevice();` using C#.

Did anyone try this before?

Comment: The code shown in your link is `driver.shake();`. Also, as the error message tells you, [shake only works on simulator](http://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver)

Comment: Thanks!! it turned out to be one of the known issues:

- shake is implemented via AppleScript and works only on Simulator due to lack of support from Apple

Answer (score 0):

As per http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/interactions/shake/

followig syntax for shake:

`driver.shake();`